# Transfer in Amsterdam International Airport

Tags: schengen, uk, transit, mexico, ams

A little background - I've always been a cautious traveler and I don't do so well in airports so I usually try to plan ahead of time, hence why I'm asking this.

In a few weeks I have a flight from MAN UK to GDL Mexico, with transfers in Amsterdam and Mexico City. I've never passed through Amsterdam before so I'm a little nervous. My flight to Amsterdam is AM 6555 (operated by KLM) and my flight between Amsterdam and Mexico City is AM 26.

Thing is, I haven't been provided with any information regarding my terminals in Amsterdam. I have tried looking it up and it appears to be split between Schengen and non-Schengen countries, although I believe I read that UK flights arrive in the same area as Schengen countries. To be honest I'm just a little bit confused as to where I will arrive and depart and therefore the security checks I should expect and whether or not I need to collect my bags in Amsterdam or check in for my Aeromexico flight.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated to put my mind at rest!

Comment: Important detail: do you have a single ticket? If yes then your bag will be through checked. The rest needs people who actually remember or can look up how Schiphol is now.

Comment: All these issues can be address when you check in for the first leg.  Ask the counter attendant for all the details of how your connections will work. And relax.  Millions of people have done it before.

Comment: UK flights use the non-Schengen part of the airport. All parts of the airport are connected airside as well as landside, so you can just walk from your arrival pier to your departure pier. You might need to pass a security check but I think you may not even have that, arriving from the UK.

Comment: @Willeke At AMS there are no security checks for pax arriving from the UK, US, Schengen zone, and several other countries.

Comment: I know that flights to Israel and sometimes to the USA have security checks just before the people board, it can be done for other destinations at need.

Comment: @cbc The AM6555 codeshare can only be bought in conjunction with a longhaul AeroMéxico flight, so I would assume this is one ticket.

Comment: Hi guys, you're right it's one ticket - I apologise for not mentioning that earlier! Thank you for all of your help, this has really put my mind at ease

Answer (score 3):

At Amsterdam airport you will deplane into the airside part of the airport. You will not need to re-clear security and (absent unusual circumstances) there is no passport check except at the gate by airline staff. You can simply walk to your next gate. The airport does not have separate "terminals" exactly but there are "piers" between which you can walk. In any event you will arrive into pier D and depart from pier F or possibly pier E. It is a ten minute walk that is clearly signed.

Assuming you booked your flights all at the same time in one transaction (as they say "on one ticket"), your bag will be transferred automatically to your Mexico City flight. (As you state that your flight from Manchester to Amsterdam has been bought with the AM6555 flight number, this must be one ticket at least as far as Mexico.)

In Mexico City, all AM flights arrive and depart at terminal 2. You will go through a passport check with all other international passengers. You will need to collect your luggage for a customs inspection. Immediately after this, there is a special place to drop your luggage so that it can be forwarded to your domestic flight. If you cannot find this, just take your bag to the domestic check in desks.

If you already have a boarding card and you dropped your bag, you can go directly to the domestic departure lounge. Otherwise, go to a check in desk. There is a light security check for domestic passengers and then you will fly over to Guadalajara. On arrival you can claim your luggage and exit the airport directly.

The return journey is similar except that your bag will be transferred automatically all the way, but you will have to re-clear security at both MEX and AMS.

Comment: You may want to change your wording, Schiphol uses the word Terminal for the different main halls, although they are interconnected.